# java simple telnet client using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I have read plenty of things on the topic, how telnet is  a protocol, not a simple socket connection, waiting for newline characters, use of external libraries and whatnot...

The bottom line is that I need a quick and dirty java telnet application up and running, not necessarily scalable and not necessarily pretty, so I'm trying to avoid the use of libraries, system function calls and the like. I have been trying and testing and so far, when trying to log into a router (through telnet of course) I have got... nothing.

Here is a snipped of the code that I have been using so far, please someone point me at the right direction because I don't know what else I should try, because I'm certain that it has to be something really simple and silly that I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 23);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

int c=0;
while ((c = r.read()) != -1)
    System.out.print((char)c);

w.print("1234\r\n"); // also tried simply \n or \r
//w.flush();
//Thread.sleep(1000);

while ((c = r.read()) != -1)
    System.out.print((char)c);

w.print("1234\r\n");
//Thread.sleep(1000);

while ((c = r.read()) != -1)
    System.out.print((char)c);

socket.close();
```

Comment: I'm aware that there are several questions on the topic already, but I have not been able to figure this out after reading those, that's why I opened a new one

Comment: https://github.com/diedas/JavaTelnetClient

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to know what's wrong with your example without testing against your particular router. It might be a good idea to use a library, for instance http://sadun-util.sourceforge.net/telnet_library.html looks like an easy one to use.

Also this site says the following:

> In order to carry on the conversation, a command is issued by simply sending it on the socket's outputstream (and using the telnet newline sequence \r\n):

```
 String command="print hello"; 
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
      new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()), true);
 pw.print(command+"\r\n");
```

> If the session appears to hang after login, avoid to wrap the StreamWriter into a PrintWriter and instead run an explicit flush() at the end:

```
 Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
 w.print(command+"\r\n");
 w.flush();
```

This might actually be the problem with your code.

Comment: I have seen that as well and Writer does not have the method print(String) so I tried with OutputStreamWriter, then print(String) and flush but still nothing. If I use regular command line telnet it works just fine so I can't think of what is wrong with it

Comment: What is the error, when does the app pause? Does it terminate?

Comment: My app first reads the first 2 lines of the login page:

        'Zyxel (something something)'
        'Login:'

And just stays there

Comment: That means your app is waiting for more input. while ((c = r.read()) != -1) will not return -1 until the socket is closed.
Either check for a string, like "Login: " and send your credentials when you receive that. You can also use blocking io with a timeout.

Comment: You were absolutely right! after changing that I finally got it working, thanks!